# How to sum every fields in a sub document of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I got a problem when I use db.collection.aggregate in MongoDB.

I have a data structure like:

```
_id:...

Segment:{
  "S1":1,
  "S2":5,
  ...
  "Sn":10
}
```

It means the following in `Segment`: I might have several sub attributes with numeric values. I'd like to sum them up as 1 + 5 + .. + 10

The problem is: I'm not sure about the sub attributes names since for each document the segment numbers are different. So I cannot list each segment name. I just want to use something like a for loop to sum all values together.

I tried queries like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([

  {$group:{
    _id:"$Account",

    total:{$sum:"$Segment.$"}
])
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You'll need to change your schema to be something like `segment: 5, value: 400` and put them in an array, or use a MapReduce. You can't do a sum on arbitrary fields.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have made the classical mistake to have arbitrary field names. MongoDB is "schema-free", but it doesn't mean you don't need to think about your schema. Key names should be descriptive, and in your case, f.e. "S2" does not really mean anything. In order to do most kinds of queries and operations, you will need to redesign you schema to store your data like this:

```
_id:...
Segment:[
    { field: "S1", value: 1 },
    { field: "S2", value: 5 },
    { field: "Sn", value: 10 },
]
```

You can then run your query like:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
    { $unwind: "$Segment" },
    { $group: {
        _id: '$_id', 
        sum: { $sum: '$Segment.value' } 
    } } 
] );
```

Which then results into something like this (with the only document from your question):

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51e4772e13573be11ac2ca6f"),
            "sum" : 16
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right. But the problem is that I have loaded whole dataset which is pretty large.. Is there any way to transform in place?

Comment: I don't think so. You'll have to write a script to do this one by one. Make sure you throttle your script though if this is already running in production.

Comment: Well, the answer was really helpful but $unwind may lead to some serious performance issues with a large dataset.So I will try thinking of a better solution first.

Comment: I think this question is similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56640054/mongodb-aggregate-fields-without-knowing-all-the-fields-before-hand

Answer (score 11):

Starting `Mongo 3.4`, this can be achieved by applying inline operations and thus avoid expensive operations such as `$group`:

```
// { _id: "xx", segments: { s1: 1, s2: 3, s3: 18, s4: 20 } }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: {
      total: { $sum: {
        $map: { input: { $objectToArray: "$segments" }, as: "kv", in: "$$kv.v" }
      }}
  }}
])
// { _id: "xx", total: 42, segments: { s1: 1, s2: 3, s3: 18, s4: 20 } }
```

The idea is to transform the object (containing the numbers to sum) as an array. This is the role of [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/), which starting `Mongo 3.4.4`, transforms `{ s1: 1, s2: 3, ... }` into `[ { k: "s1", v: 1 }, { k: "s2", v: 3 }, ... ]`. This way, we don't need to care about the field names since we can access values through their `"v"` fields.

Having an array rather than an object is a first step towards being able to sum its elements. But the elements obtained with `$objectToArray` are objects and not simple integers. We can get passed this by mapping (the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operation) these array elements to extract the value of their `"v"` field. Which in our case results in creating this kind of array: `[1, 3, 18, 42]`.

Finally, it's a simple matter of summing elements within this array, using the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operation.

Comment: Nice idea. This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Segment: {s1: 10, s2: 4, s3: 12}

```
{$set: {"new_array":{$objectToArray: "$Segment"}}}, //makes field names all "k" or "v"
{$project: {_id:0, total:{$sum: "$new_array.v"}}}
```

"total" will be 26.

$set replaces $addFields in newer versions of mongo. (I'm using 4.2.)

```
"new_array": [
                {
                    "k": "s1",
                    "v": 10
                },
                {
                    "k": "s2",
                    "v": 4
                },
                {
                    "k": "s3",
                    "v": 12
                }
            ]
```

You can also use regular expressions. Eg. `/^s/i` for words starting with "s".